# How to use AR Core in LG V30?

Tags: arcore

I'm intending to create a simple Android app with AR Core. Unfortunately, my current phone is not compatible with Google Play Service for AR.
So I intend to buy a second-handed LG V30 to use for my app.
The problem is, LG V30, is listed in AR supported device, but there's a note that "ARCore uses the wide angle fixed focus rear facing camera for AR tracking". What does that mean? And will it affect my project? My project worked on Samsung Galaxy Note 8, do I need to modify it when testing on LG V30?
Also, I found some articles say that some LG smartphones, include LG V30, doesn't support autofocus. That's related to my question, right?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Google AR Core](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core&hl=en_IN) to access the AR Core feature! The wideangle issue may affect the end result on other devices which does not use wideangle! But still you app will work on other devices

[AR Core Supported Devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) Check the list for other devices and features!

Comment: hi, thank you for replying to me. I mentioned that LG V30 is on the AR Core supported device list. Actually I have not bought the LG V30 yet, since I see the autofocus error, I confuse if I should buy it for developing ar app or shouldn't.